# Is it possible for MUI autocomplete to be linked with two field values?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

Hi I am trying to make a custom search input where user could click on it and be shown the possible filter categories they could select. Also they can optionally type a title keyword to then search with the title and the categories filter selected. A very good example of what I am trying to do is the telegram bugs website search bar. https://bugs.telegram.org/

So i was thinking of using mui autocomplete where when user selects the category it will populate some field state called categories containing an array of selected category. Then when the user types a custom text it will then be stored in keyword field. Is it even possible to do so? If not is there a better approach to do this.

Comment: Maybe the [chip select](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/#chip) in combination with the [useAutocomplete](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#useautocomplete) hook could help you create the custom input?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with the help of `multiple`, `freeSolo` and `filterSelectedOptions` props.
I have made a working example similar to your case, You can find it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-8t1wvc?file=App.tsx)

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';

const options = [{ value:'1', label:'One'}, { value:'2', label:'Two'}, { value:'3', label:'Three'},];

export default function App() {
  const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState([]);

  return (
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        freeSolo
        filterSelectedOptions
        options={options}
        onChange={(_, value) => {
           setSelectedOptions(value);
         }}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label="Multiple values"
            placeholder="Add value"
         />
      )}
   />
 );
}
```